# How does the npm package-lock file generate the dependency tree?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I have a project (`node.js 14 + npm 6`) that has a dependency let's call it `A`.
`A` also has a dependency called `B`.
After I run `npm install` the package lock file has `B` under `A` as a transient dependency to my project:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "A": {
      ...
      "dependencies": {
        "B": {
          ...
        },
      }
    },
  }
}
```

However, if I delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` lock file will change to this:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "A": {
      ...
    },
    "B": {
      ...
    },
  }
}
```

Both `A` and `B` are on the same level in the tree structure. Nothing has been changed in the `package.json` and all other files remained the same between the two installs.

My questions are:

- Why is it happening?
- Is it a normal thing to happen?
- Doesn't this makes collaboration cumbersome? Every time someone touches `npm i` the packages lock file changes.